# Circuit simulation: Why this circuit is not working as a switch?

Tags: transistors, simulation, power-electronics

[image]

I'm a Newbie Electronics student, trying to simulate a switching circuit using 2 diodes.
I was able to get the expected result during experimentation, but when I sketched the same circuit in a simulator [Multisim 12.0] I'm not getting the expected result.

When I provide High Voltage to the **Base**, output signal must be **Low voltage**. Why am I getting this result?

Could you please explain where I'm wrong?

Comment: "trying to simulate a switching circuit using 2 diodes" A transistor is more than just 2 diodes.

Comment: Note that you connected a multimeter directly to the 5V bus. Now think in what kind of scenario that bus will not be 5V.

Comment: And putting 5V on a diode (without a series resistor) isn't a good idea either.

Comment: @WesleyLee https://cdn.sparkfun.com/assets/learn_tutorials/1/9/3/logic-inverter-circuit.png

Comment: @ShrishailTalukar -- Care to elaborate..?

Comment: @WesleyLee Sorry for just redirecting the link [I thought you would understand without explanation]. I added a resistor as shown in that illustration, but I'm getting the same result.

Comment: Well, you do not have a resistor in the image you posted on the question. We have no way to guess that the schematic you provided is actually different from the one you are testing. If you modified it please update the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First there are some faults in the wiring. You are measuring the 5V rail. In this circuit the multimeter will always measure 5V. This can be solved by adding a resistor (5k to 50k) between the 5V and the transistor (collector). Also add a resistor (500 to 1k) to the base of the transistor.

The diode circuit does not work like the transistor equivalent. Yes, both diodes are PN material the difference between the diodes and transistor is the space between them. A transistor is PNP or NPN next to each other.

Some transistors can be used as a (double) diodes. It's not possible to create a transistor with two diodes.

Comment: Also the reason you may have seen the correct results with the transistor during an experiment is because in the real world there will be resistors in the circuit, the wires and power supplies aren't perfect and the power supply could well be current limiting. The simulation ignores these real world imperfections unless you tell it to include them.